# Grails Domain Validator: Two fields, either can be null, but not both

Tags: unit-testing, validation, grails

I have a domain where there are two fields that can either be null, but not both at the same time.  So something like this

```
class Character {
    Association association
    String otherAssociation
    static constraints = {
        association (validator: {val, obj->  if (!val && !obj.otherAssociation) return 'league.association.mustbeone'})
        otherAssociation (validator: {val, obj->  if (!val && !obj.association) return 'league.association.mustbeone'})
    }
}
```

But when I run tests like the following, i only get failures

```
void testCreateWithAssociation() {
   def assoc = new Association(name:'Fake Association').save()
   def assoccha = new Character(association:assoc).save()

   assert assoccha
}
void testCreateWithoutAssociation() {
    def cha = new Character(otherAssociation:'Fake Association').save()
    assert cha
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**
It looks like if I break out my code into something like this:

```
def assoc = new Association(name:'Fake Association')
assoc.save()
```

Everything works fine.  But now I would like to know why I can't have .save() in the same line as I do this in other tests and it works.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Try to put back .save() in same line as before. Maybe your class or some other code wasn't reloaded or something other change in mean time. Is hard to believe that this change would affect test case.

Comment: The `.save()` method returns `false` if the domain failed validation, and returns the domain class if it passed validation. Just FYI

Answer (score 5):

In order to make your test pass, your fields association and otherAssociation must be null. Add nullable constraint to both, like that:

```
static constraints = {
    association nullable: true, validator: {val, obj->  if (!val && !obj.otherAssociation) return 'league.association.mustbeone'}
    otherAssociation nullable: true, validator: {val, obj->  if (!val && !obj.association) return 'league.association.mustbeone'}
}
```

I tried it and it works